# Making a custom font an animated SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg, fonts

I am trying to figure out how to animate a font in the same way it is being done on this site.

http://weaintplastic.com/

If you start scrolling you can see the section headings animating in. The font for those headings is the same as the body font, so it seems like he converted the font to SVG paths and animated it, but I can't figure out how to convert a font of mine into something like that. I get the basics of how to make it animate (with stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset) but I don't know how to convert a font into the right types of paths.

I typed some words into Sketch and converted them to vectors and exported to SVG and here is what I got.

```
<svg width="462px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 462 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <path d="M0.032,35 L7.28,35 L7.28,13.208 L16.64,27.416 L16.832,27.416 L26.288,13.064 L26.288,35 L33.632,35 L33.632,1.4 L25.664,1.4 L16.832,15.608 L8,1.4 L0.032,1.4 L0.032,35 Z M41.696,35 L67.28,35 L67.28,28.424 L49.04,28.424 L49.04,21.368 L64.88,21.368 L64.88,14.792 L49.04,14.792 L49.04,7.976 L67.04,7.976 L67.04,1.4 L41.696,1.4 L41.696,35 Z M73.856,35 L99.44,35 L99.44,28.424 L81.2,28.424 L81.2,21.368 L97.04,21.368 L97.04,14.792 L81.2,14.792 L81.2,7.976 L99.2,7.976 L99.2,1.4 L73.856,1.4 L73.856,35 Z M113.84,35 L121.232,35 L121.232,8.216 L131.456,8.216 L131.456,1.4 L103.616,1.4 L103.616,8.216 L113.84,8.216 L113.84,35 Z M159.344,35 L166.736,35 L166.736,8.216 L176.96,8.216 L176.96,1.4 L149.12,1.4 L149.12,8.216 L159.344,8.216 L159.344,35 Z M182.624,35 L190.016,35 L190.016,21.512 L203.648,21.512 L203.648,35 L211.04,35 L211.04,1.4 L203.648,1.4 L203.648,14.696 L190.016,14.696 L190.016,1.4 L182.624,1.4 L182.624,35 Z M219.104,35 L244.688,35 L244.688,28.424 L226.448,28.424 L226.448,21.368 L242.288,21.368 L242.288,14.792 L226.448,14.792 L226.448,7.976 L244.448,7.976 L244.448,1.4 L219.104,1.4 L219.104,35 Z M265.664,35 L273.056,35 L273.056,24.92 L278.672,24.92 C286.208,24.92 292.256,20.888 292.256,13.112 L292.256,13.016 C292.256,6.152 287.408,1.4 279.392,1.4 L265.664,1.4 L265.664,35 Z M273.056,18.344 L273.056,8.072 L278.768,8.072 C282.464,8.072 284.768,9.848 284.768,13.16 L284.768,13.256 C284.768,16.136 282.608,18.344 278.912,18.344 L273.056,18.344 Z M291.488,35 L299.024,35 L302.096,27.464 L316.304,27.464 L319.376,35 L327.104,35 L312.704,1.16 L305.888,1.16 L291.488,35 Z M304.736,20.936 L309.2,10.04 L313.664,20.936 L304.736,20.936 Z M343.76,35.48 C351.008,35.48 356.096,31.736 356.096,25.064 L356.096,24.968 C356.096,19.112 352.256,16.664 345.44,14.888 C339.632,13.4 338.192,12.68 338.192,10.472 L338.192,10.376 C338.192,8.744 339.68,7.448 342.512,7.448 C345.344,7.448 348.272,8.696 351.248,10.76 L355.088,5.192 C351.68,2.456 347.504,0.92 342.608,0.92 C335.744,0.92 330.848,4.952 330.848,11.048 L330.848,11.144 C330.848,17.816 335.216,19.688 341.984,21.416 C347.6,22.856 348.752,23.816 348.752,25.688 L348.752,25.784 C348.752,27.752 346.928,28.952 343.904,28.952 C340.064,28.952 336.896,27.368 333.872,24.872 L329.504,30.104 C333.536,33.704 338.672,35.48 343.76,35.48 L343.76,35.48 Z M369.632,35 L377.024,35 L377.024,8.216 L387.248,8.216 L387.248,1.4 L359.408,1.4 L359.408,8.216 L369.632,8.216 L369.632,35 Z M407.792,35.576 C418.16,35.576 425.696,27.752 425.696,18.2 L425.696,18.104 C425.696,8.552 418.256,0.824 407.888,0.824 C397.52,0.824 389.984,8.648 389.984,18.2 L389.984,18.296 C389.984,27.848 397.424,35.576 407.792,35.576 L407.792,35.576 Z M407.888,28.76 C401.936,28.76 397.712,23.96 397.712,18.2 L397.712,18.104 C397.712,12.344 401.84,7.64 407.792,7.64 C413.744,7.64 417.968,12.44 417.968,18.2 L417.968,18.296 C417.968,24.056 413.84,28.76 407.888,28.76 L407.888,28.76 Z M432.272,35 L439.664,35 L439.664,24.248 L445.472,24.248 L452.672,35 L461.312,35 L453.104,23 C457.376,21.416 460.304,18.008 460.304,12.584 L460.304,12.488 C460.304,9.32 459.296,6.68 457.424,4.808 C455.216,2.6 451.904,1.4 447.632,1.4 L432.272,1.4 L432.272,35 Z M439.664,17.72 L439.664,8.072 L447.008,8.072 C450.608,8.072 452.816,9.704 452.816,12.872 L452.816,12.968 C452.816,15.8 450.752,17.72 447.152,17.72 L439.664,17.72 Z" id="MEET-THE-PASTOR" fill="#000000" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Not exactly what I want because I need each letter to be a separate path, but I also need each one to be in the right format to animate.

Comment: Instead, read the source for that page. The text is uses lots of elements for individual letters, each animated on their own, so the best way to get your answer is not to ask it on Stackoverflow, but to first contact the people who run that site, to ask them if they're using something that you too can use.

Comment: I've read the source code. I know how he is doing it and how the animation is working. I just wanted to know if there was either 1) a way to convert my font quickly to the right format so I can animate it or 2) a way to animate what I have. I know more people are constantly checking this site then he probably checks and responds to his emails so I figured I could get a quicker response here, otherwise I'm going to find other options (which yes, will include asking him directly). Thanks for your help though.

Comment: it might be useful if you set up a small codepen that shows what you already understand, so that you can narrow your question to "I already have these things:..., but I'm stuck on this part:...". Right now, you're asking a really broad thing (I know fonts, but I'm not going to research how they do what they do, for instance, just to answer what the best way to convert them is. I expect you to find out what form you need, and then explain that in the context of a minimal working example, so I can recommend how to achieve a useful conversion)